# Jenkins and IE11 tests

Tags: c#, jenkins, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

Has anyone else had problems with the IE 11 browser when the tests were ran by Jenkins?
For some reason, running the tests locally with the debugger or with the NUnit cause no problems but as soon as the test is loaded in Jenkins, everything that's set to run in IE fails after login.
It's strange because Chrome and Firefox don't seem to have a problem with Jenkins and even IE manages to open the page and login, but as soon as it has to find a radio button it crashes. And only with Jenkins

For the record i use selenium webdriver with c# and the the test looks something like this:

```
public void ItemSearch()
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
        // Select the item

            var ItemBTN = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='articleSearch_rb']"));
            var ItemInput = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='articleSearch']"));
            var SearchBTN = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='buttonSearch']"));
            ItemBTN.Click();
            ItemInput.SendKeys("This item");
            SearchBTN.Click();
     }
```

IE crashes after failing to find the first element (ItemBTN)

Comment: What do you mean by 'only with jenkins'? Did you trigger the test manually in the slave machine? Did it work?

Comment: How does your slave is configured ? Do you login into slave PC and run jenkins slave agent manually, ? Or the slave agent is running as a Windows service ? IE requires an opened desktop, all the time, if desktop is locked, then tests will fail.

Comment: we have a virtual server where jenkins is installed, on the same machine we have the tests uploaded. The only problems is when the tests run on IE (11)